# Error When Collecting Data from Dialog Box to Update Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I'm trying to create a dialog box using Google Apps Script that collects a user's name and then updates a specific cell in a Google Sheet with a greeting. The dialog box appears correctly, but when I click the submit button, I receive a useless error in the console. See screenshot below

Here's the code I'm using:

**HTML (dialog.html):**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm">
      <label for="name">Enter Your Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="name">
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="collectData()">
    </form>
    <script>
      function collectData() {
        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(closeDialog)
          .withFailureHandler(function(error) { console.error('ERROR:', error); })
          .updateSheet(name)
      }

      function closeDialog() {
        google.script.host.close();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Google Apps Script:**

```js
function showDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('dialog')
      .setWidth(300)
      .setHeight(200);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Enter Your Name');
}

function updateSheet(name) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange('A1').setValue('Hello, ' + name + '!');
}

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show Dialog', 'showDialog')
      .addToUi();
}
```

The modal window opens and looks fine, but the submit button results in this error that gives no useful information. I've checked the HTML content, permissions, and browser compatibility and manually executed the functions, but the issue persists. I've also tried logging something in the `updateSheet()` function, but nothing gets logged.

[image: screenshot]

Has anyone encountered this error before, or is something wrong with my code that I'm overlooking? I've checked tutorials on this feature of sheets, and it seems I'm doing everything right.

---

**Update:**

I tried using `event.preventDefault()` in the form's `onsubmit` handler to prevent the default form submission action, as suggested, also the "duplicate" questions had nothing to do with this, as they were related to the page refreshing which is not happening here. but just for giggles I tried adding `onsubmit="return false"` to the form and just turning the button into purely an `onclick` function, and that didnt work either:

```html
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="collectData(event)">
  <!-- ... -->
</form>
<script>
  function collectData(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // ...
  }
</script>
```

Unfortunately, this change did not resolve the issue, and I'm still encountering the same error.

---

Hopefully, someone with experience in this specific area or who has faced a similar issue can provide insight into what might be going wrong.

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` is missing in the form submission event. There might be other problems.

Comment: @Rubén my original "form" was not a form, the submission event is only prevalent in a form submit, this was simply a button named Submit with an onclick handler. but either way, I tried turning this into a form with an `e.preventDefault()` and nothing changed.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The client side code shows a form tag.

Comment: Regarding what is shown in the console, you can ignore the first row. The second and third rows are added by google.script.run, basically, they say that the server-side code was called and it responded.

Comment: The fourth row is hard to read because  console.error statement is passing two argument, the second argument is an object. You might want to pass some of the object parameters like error.message and error.stack

Comment: I copied your project as is and run it from the menu and it works.  So what is wrong on your end is not reproducable.